# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php

---

Buenos días, es que estoy haciendo una página y estoy haciendo la conexión a la base de datos pero me manda el siguiente error

```
<?php 
    require 'init.php';

    class Funciones{

        public function getPublicaciones(){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare("
                SELECT *
                FROM blog
            ");
            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetchALL();
        }
    }
?>
```

Y lo estoy llamando así:

```
<?php 
    require 'php/Funciones.php';
    $obj = new Funciones();

    $publicaciones = $obj->getPublicaciones();

    echo '<pre>', print_r($publicaciones), '</pre>';
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: y donde estas haciendo la conexión?

Comment: es decir como haces que llegue `$pdo` ?

Comment: la conexion la tengo aqui                                                                       '<?php  
 try {
  $pdon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ineaco', 'root',''); 
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "No se puede conectar a la base de datos. Error;" . $e;
 }

?>'